# Get Hunchentoot to output no headers at all

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, hunchentoot

I want to return a TSV file from a web call in Hunchentoot (SBCL), but want the user to just save the raw result blatted to the page, rather than use a separate file and download link (which is hard because of local firewall complexities).

I can't figure out how to output the page without any headers at all, i.e., to make it just plain raw text. (I know that the browser would make a mess w/o headers in the DOM, but don't care; the goal is just to have the user save the page, not read it.)

I've tried various combinations of

`(setf (hunchentoot:content-type*) "text/plain")`

and

```
(cl-who:with-html-output-to-string                                                                                            
          (*standard-output* nil :prologue nil)
```

and setting the content-type* inside, outside, and around the with... but I always get header junk.

Comment: the header is part of the http protocol, I am not sure I understand what you want to do

Comment: I just want to send over raw text that I totally control. Hunchentoot seems to insist on adding headers. I want to completely dictate what it sends, headers and all, and in this case, I’d leave them off entirely (as well as the matching /body /html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Writing a string directly

I tried defining a handler as follows:

```
(define-easy-handler (text :uri "/text") ()
  (setf (content-type*) "text/csv")
  "a,b,c")
```

When I visit the page locally, the browser automatically downloads a text file without even displaying (this is probably a setting we can change in Chrome, I don't know).

When I enable the browser developer mode, here are the response headers I receive as part of the HTTP protocol:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ...
Date: ...
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 5
Connection: keep-alive
```

But the file itself is just the string `a,b,c`.

If I change the content-type to `"text/plain"`, then the browser successfully displays the text, and nothing else (the HTTP headers are the same).

#### Remarks

You don't need to use the `cl-who` macros if you do not intend to build an HTML document, in fact its better not to. In any case, you can supply your own `REPLY-CLASS` when initializing the acceptor (see https://edicl.github.io/hunchentoot/#replies) and have a very low-level control about what you emit as a reply, headers included. But I don't think this is necessary in your case. I don't clearly understand where your problem comes from, but sending back a plain text is something the framework is supposed to be able to do out of the box. Please add more details if you can.

Comment: One minor detail that it's made entirely clear in the docs (or at least not clear to me, but I might have simply missed it!) is that you need (with-output-to-string ...), which is why I was using cl-who:with-html-output-to-string. The typical usage is: (with-output-to-string (\*standard-output\* nil) ...)

Comment: Oh thanks, you're right write-line was not necessary, it worked because the function returns its argument

Answer (score 0):

Is the correct answer not to use the [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header?